# How do i call this indicator?

Tags: mql4

```
input int    BackLimit   = 10000;
input int    TimeFrame   = 0;
input string TimeString  = "0=Current, 15=M15, 30=M30, 60=H1, 240=H4, 1440=Day, 10080=Week, 43200=Month";



input string  SHOW_ZONES            = "==========SHOW ZONES==========";
input bool   zone_show_untested     = true;
input bool   zone_show_verified     = true;
input bool   zone_show_truncoat     = true;
input bool   zone_show_weak         = false;
input bool   zone_show_possible     = false;
input bool   zone_showbroken        = false;

input string  ZONE_ALERTS           = "==========ZONE ALERTS==========";
input bool   zone_show_alerts       = true;
input bool   zone_alert_popups      = true;
input bool   zone_alert_sounds      = true;
input bool   send_email             = false;
input bool   use_push               = false;
input int    zone_alert_waitseconds = 300; 

input string  ZONE_ALERTS_FILTER    = "==========FILTER ALERTS==========";
input bool   filter_zone_alert      = true;
input bool   filter_MA              = true;
input  int   TF_MA                  = 60;
input  int   MA_FAST_PERIOD         = 13;
input  int   MA_FAST_METHOD         = 1;
input  int   MA_SLOW_PERIOD         = 48;
input  int   MA_SLOW_METHOD         = 1;


input string  STYLE_ZONES            = "==========STYLE ZONES==========";
input bool   zone_merge             = true;
input bool   zone_extend            = false;
input bool   zone_solid             = false;
input int    zone_linewidth         = 1;
input int    zone_style             = 0;
input int    ShiftEndRight          = 3;//extend the end of zones 3 bars beyond last bar
input int    zone_limit             = 1000;
input bool   zone_show_info         = true;
input bool   zone_show_size         = true;
input int    zone_label_shift       = 3;
input color  color_label            = clrWhite; //Label color
input string font_label             = "Courier New"; //Label Font
input int    size_label             = 9; //Label size

input string  ZONES_COLOR             = "==========COLOR ZONES==========";
input color   color_support_possible  = DarkSlateGray;
input color   color_support_untested  = SeaGreen;
input color   color_support_verified  = Green;
input color   color_support_weak      = LimeGreen;
input color   color_support_turncoat  = OliveDrab;
input color   color_resist_possible   = Indigo;
input color   color_resist_untested   = Orchid;
input color   color_resist_verified   = Crimson;
input color   color_resist_weak       = Red;
input color   color_resist_turncoat   = DarkOrange;
input color   color_broken_weak       = DarkGray;
input color   color_broken_verified   = Gray;
input color   color_broken_other      = DimGray;

input string  ZONE_FRACTALS         = "==========ZONE FRACTALS==========";
input double zone_fuzzfactor        = 0.75;
input bool   fractals_show          = false;
input double fractal_fast_factor    = 3.0;
input double fractal_slow_factor    = 6.0;

input string  ZONES_GLOBAL_VAR      = "==========ZONES GLOBAL VARIABLES==========";
input bool   SetGlobals             = False;

input string  ZONES_TESTING_MODE    = "==========ZONES TESTING==========";
input bool   Testing                = false; //TRUE == scrolling back the chart shows PAST zone "look"
input bool   ShowTestingBtn         = false; //Show button to switch Testing mode On/Off
input int    TestingBtnX            = 10; //Position of this button
input int    TestingBtnY            = 120;

    double lineOne = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"SS_SupportResistance_v07.53 (filter alerts MA)",BackLimit,TimeFrame,TimeString, SHOW_ZONES,zone_show_untested,zone_show_verified,zone_show_truncoat,zone_show_weak,zone_show_possible,zone_showbroken,ZONE_ALERTS,zone_show_alerts,zone_alert_popups,zone_alert_sounds,send_email,use_push,zone_alert_waitseconds,ZONE_ALERTS_FILTER,filter_zone_alert,filter_MA,TF_MA,MA_FAST_PERIOD,MA_FAST_METHOD,MA_SLOW_PERIOD,MA_SLOW_METHOD,STYLE_ZONES,zone_merge,zone_extend,zone_solid,zone_linewidth,zone_style,ShiftEndRight,zone_limit,zone_show_info,zone_show_size,zone_label_shift,color_label,font_label,size_label,ZONES_COLOR,color_support_possible,color_support_untested,color_support_verified,color_support_weak,color_support_turncoat,color_resist_possible,color_resist_untested,color_resist_verified,color_resist_weak,color_resist_turncoat,color_broken_weak,color_broken_verified,color_broken_other,ZONE_FRACTALS,zone_fuzzfactor,fractals_show,fractal_fast_factor,fractal_slow_factor,ZONES_GLOBAL_VAR,SetGlobals,ZONES_TESTING_MODE,Testing,ShowTestingBtn,TestingBtnX,TestingBtnY,0,1);
       Print("The number is ",lineOne);
```

These are the inputs of the indicator i want to call. I have done similar calling for another indicator and it worked. This specific indicator is giving "wrong parameter count" error. After calling the indicator inputs, the zero, the second to the last parameter represent the line with buffer 0, while the 1 which is the last parameter represent the last candle. Please what could wrong. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

cause the inputSettings have Placeholders like: "==========BLABLABLA==========";
u need to adjust ur iCustom call everytime when u have Placeholder like that u need to put a "0" in ur iCustom function call

pls like if it helps